# Wrong results in Laravel eloquent query using date filter

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have to extract results from DB having date column bigger than today (basically i need to see the up coming events).

In real world I play in my MySql console:

```
select * from searcheable where MATCH (title,description) AGAINST ('rock' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and date > CURDATE() order by date  asc
```

And it works well.

I'm trying to extract same data in eloquent style using Laravel, and I wrote:

```
$results = Search::search($key)
            ->whereDate("date",">",' CURDATE()')
            ->orderBy("date",'asc')
            ->paginate();
```

But it returns wrong results having wrong date.

Note the *search* metohd I used is for a fulltext. I don't think it's the issue.

If I do a debug and I print the sql using dd($results) it return:

```
select * from `searcheable` where MATCH (title,description) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) and date(`date`) > ? order by `date` asc
```

which is very similar to the starting query I'm working on.

What's wrong in my eloquent query?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: You are comparing with the constant string `' CURDATE()'`. Try `DB::raw('CURDATE()')` instead. Or pass the current date from PHP.

Comment: Or you can compare it like `->whereDate("date",">",date('Y-m-d'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this

```
 ->whereDate("date",">", now());
```

`now()` will return a Carbon DateTime instance, Which will be automatically casted to appropriate format

Comment: Sure! I was waiting the regular time :) It avoid to accept answers too fast

Answer (score 1):

As it looks probably your error is in the `CURDATE()` format, you need to be sure both dates are in the same format, for the currentdate I always use `$currentdate = Carbon::now();`

then use this date for your search...

Comment: Thanks for help. It works using date() instead of 'CURDATE()'. I'll do a check to carbon documentation... Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Sure it's another way to use the Carbon library, similar to use now() directly, but using the variable you could acces the methods